# How do you transfer data from SQL Server to db4o?

Tags: sql-server, db4o

I came across this question after searching for a ODBC or JDBC. To my surprise, since I am new to db4o I found there are tools to browse db4o, including a Netbeans and Eclipse plug in. However, when it comes to the question at hand, I only found one company, and the product is not being sold nor demoed (makes me think is not ready yet).

So, how do you transfer data? Is there a tool or script I have not found yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data transfer between db4o and relational Databases (in both direction) can be easily done with db4o's tool: [dRS - db4o Replication System](http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/drs/) (based on Hibernate). 
BTW, db4o user forum might be very useful, you will get answers directly from core developers.

Answer (score 2):

That's right. When it comes to db4o's dRS, in order to move your data to a relational database you need to define a Hibernate mapping. But it's definitely the way to go for this kind of migration if you don't want to do it all by yourself.

Best!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this comes down to the [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).  Which is to say, except in very simple cases, there isn't necessarily a direct translation from a database row to an object.  Your object model is fundamentally different than your database schema.  Therefore, I would imagine that in most cases, you will have to come up with the mapping (and a migration application) yourself.

This goes generally for any relational database/object database, not just SQL Server and db4o.